# Is product of Lebesgue integrable functions also Lebesgue integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> If $ f, g \in L(I), $ does $ fg \in L(I)$?

I tried to solve this that way:

> $f$ and  $g$ are Lebesgue integrable for each function there is a sequence of step function ${f_n}$ and ${g_n}$ that satisfy:
>
> - ${f_n}$ and ${g_n}$ are increasing, bounded and $ f_n \rightarrow f , g_n \rightarrow g $
> - $ \int_{I} f_n, \int_{I} g_n $ is bounded
>
> so the sequence $\{f_n g_n\}$ satisfy those conditions and therefore $fg \in L(I)$

Am I right?

thanks

Comment: The issue is the second bullet: the integrals of the products needn't be bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $I$ is an interval of $\mathbb R$, then the answer is negative. Take $I=(0,1]$, and $f(x)=g(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}$.

Comment: Note that even if we ask for $I$ to be closed, we can just set $f(0)=g(0)=0$, since we don't require any kind of continuity.